# Java JSoup: Could not parse query ... unexpected token at /

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm learning jsoup using a news article about football (https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/66241967).

My goal is to extract the text body of the news article.

Since the text body of the article seems to sit within multiple spans of a div class called `qa-story-body story-body gel-pica gel-10/12@m gel-7/8@l gs-u-ml0@l gs-u-pb++`, I want to extract all spans within that div class.

[image]

The problem is that instead of my expected output I get an error (see code below).

Why can't the query be parsed?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;  
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;  
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Footballnews{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/66244696").get(); 
        Elements spans = document.select("div.qa-story-body.story-body.gel-pica.gel-10/12@m.gel-7/8@l.gs-u-ml0@l.gs-u-pb++ span");
        for (Element span: spans) {
            System.out.println(span.text());
        }  
    }
}
```

I get this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException:
> Could not parse query 'div.qa-story-body.story-body.gel-pica.gel-10/12@m.gel-7/8@l.gs-u-ml0@l.gs-u-pb++ span':
> unexpected token at '/12@m.gel-7/8@l.gs-u-ml0@l.gs-u-pb++ span'

I expected the text:

> Brazilian civil servants can report to work up to four hours late - two hours after the end of matches - when the national side play in the 2023 Women's World Cup. The competition gets under way on Thursday in Australia and New Zealand. Brazil play their opening game on Monday against Panama in Adelaide.....

Answer (score 0):

Probably all the special characters (@/+) causing parsing problem in your selctor.
If you look at the desired text, it belongs to a div that starts with "qa-story-body", so the first step will be to fetch this div simply by using `div.qa-story-body`, but this div also includes some redundent text which can be found in the `ul` at the bottom of it. Luckily, all the paragraphs that you want start with the `p` tag, so you can use the selector `div.qa-story-body > p` to get only the text of the article.
Full code:

```
String url = "https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/66241967";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements spans = doc.select("div.qa-story-body > p");
for (Element sp : spans) {
    System.out.println(sp.text());
}
```